# vuejs auto refresh list after request

Tags: vue.js

I have a form adding new contact to the data base:

```
<el-form :model="contact" >
            <el-form-item>
              <el-input v-model="contact.firstname"/>
            </el-form-item>
         <el-form-item>
          <el-input v-model="contact.lastname"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
          <el-button @click="submitForm">Save
          </el-button>
      </el-form>
```

I get the list of all the contacts:

```
async getContacts() {
      this.getcontacts = await ContactApi().get();
      this.arraycontacts = this.getcontacts.contactsList;
    },
```

and when I submit the form I would like the list to auto refresh:

```
 <div v-for="contact in arraycontacts">
    <div>{{ contact.firstname }}</div>
    <div>{{ contact.lastname }}</div>           
 </div>
```

I've seen some solution on the internet but all using axios or ajax which I am not, in what way can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your submit handler get the response from the server and assign it to your list of contacts

```
methods: {
  async submitForm() {
  {
    this.getcontacts = await ContactApi().submit(this.contact);
    this.arraycontacts = this.getcontacts.contactsList; 
  }
```